# VBA to remove duplicates when one column has specific value

Tags: excel, vba

could some one please assist me in this?

i have a situation where i need to delete duplicate rows with "ok" and "cancelled". need only status ="met".

note: file has more than 5k rows.

```
number | status   |
123       ok
123       met
123       cancelled
124       ok
125       met
```

Comment: Data/Filter
Then select OK and Canceled from the filter and delete

Comment: What if `number` field is not duplicate and status is `OK`. do you still need to remove this row?

Comment: like `124 - ok` in your example

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove "**duplicates**" that have  a status of OK or cancelled, then add a column next to your data, and use this formula (For me the data is in col A and B and I have added col C)

```
C2 =AND(SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:$A$6000=A2))>1,OR(B2="ok",B2="cancelled"))
```

Drag this all the way down

the got Data -> Filter. Filter(keep) TRUE only in the third column. Select the rows in the filtered data and delete.

Remove the filter. You should be left with the desired rows